# How to access SQL Server from my WCF web service?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, wcf

VS Express 2012, SQL Server Express 2012, Win 8.1

Hello,

I have a (very) simple WCF hosted as a web service on IIS. I also have a SQL Server instance (with 1 table) installed on the same machine.

I need a step-by-step guide on how to connect to SQL from the WCF (VB) and retrieve a single record from the table (ie: "SELECT LAST NAME FROM MYTABLE WHERE PK = 1;"). That's it. I don't need a 1,200 page manual -- which is all Google keeps throwing at me.

Anyone know of a quick, clean resource?

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main classes that are involved are [SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). The documentation of the classes contains some samples on how to use them. To get you started, here is a small sample:

```
Dim connStr = "Data Source=SQLServerName\InstanceName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI"
Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
    conn.Open()
    Using cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT LAST_NAME FROM MYTABLE WHERE PK = @pk"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pk", 1)
        Dim result = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        If Typeof result Is DbNull Then
            ' Handle null value
        Else
            ' Otherwise
        End If
    End Using
End Using
```

This sample assumes that you want to retrieve a single cell as in your statement. If you want to retrieve tabular data, have a look a the [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) or [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class.
Please note that - especially in server applications - it is important to dispose of the created instances properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference on using ADO.NET in a WCF service or in a normal application from the point of view of the classes required.

The first thing needed is a connection string that allows your SqlConnection object to find the host and the database that you want to use. [Here examples on connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/)

Then you usually need a SqlCommand that encapsulates the SQL text and parameters needed to retrieve  the data (Here you setup your SELECT statement and conditions)

Finally you need a SqlDataReader that get the result of the command execution and allows you to loop over the results.

[Here a sample that could get you started.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#_SqlClient)

Keep in mind that this is just a minimal todo-list and there are numerous other ways to work with data. Basic objects like SqlDataAdapter, Dataset, DataTable present different ways to load data from a database and use that data. Then on top of these there are technologies like [Linq To Sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Object Relational Mapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) tools that abstract the data access and offer high level functionality on top of data.

That's probably the reason you get so much informations on data access technologies